# Development version on PyPI

Tags: python, pip, packaging, easy-install, pypi

In [this 2011 post](http://ziade.org/2011/02/15/do-not-upload-dev-releases-at-pypi/), it is argued that dev versions should not be uploaded to PyPI. Is this now (May 2013) still the case? If not, what is the suggested way to distribute development version of a Python Package.

Comment: Related: My question [pip - installation of the latest stable version of package](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/distutils-sig/d82cQUhvqjA) asked on distutils-sig mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

This is still not a good practice to upload package development version to PyPI.

For example, look at Django, it has only stable versions on PyPI (`yolk -V django`):

```
Django 1.5.1
Django 1.5
Django 1.4.5
Django 1.4.4
Django 1.4.3
Django 1.3.7
Django 1.3.6
Django 1.3.5
Django 1.2.7
Django 1.1.4
Django 1.0.4
```

lxml (the most [popular](http://pypi-ranking.info/alltime) package on PyPI), again, only stable versions:

```
lxml 3.2.1
lxml 3.2.0
lxml 3.1.2
lxml 3.1.1
lxml 3.1.0
```

The latest development version is usually installed directly from the module repository (e.g. [django dev version](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)).

Hope that helps.